# как вывести изображение записи wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

как вывести изображение записи wordpress, без цикла?

это не работает `the_post_thumbnail([260, 412]);`

```
$arr = [
    'post_count' => 1,
    'cat' => 39,

];

$recent = new WP_Query($arr);
```

В объекте `$recent->post` есть куча всего, но нет изображение записи, как его получить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция the_post_thumbnail() работает только в цикле с текущим постом. Чтобы вывести изображение в вашем случае, надо использовать get_the_post_thumbnail(), которой можно передать пост первым параметром.

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $recent->post, [260, 412])
```